# How to pass formdata in swagger with require ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger

Hai i want to pass formdata in my put request in swagger. But when i upload the file it gives me parameter missing user. I know that i have specified it as required in my controller but how to pass even though i have set this.

The controller code is

```
 def update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :designation,:profile_image,:cover_image)
 end
```

My swagger code is

```
parameter do
       key :name, :profile_image
       key :in, :formData
       key :type, :file
       key :format, :binary
       key :required, false
       schema do
         key :'$ref', :UserInput
       end
     end
```

The error i am getting is

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: user):
```

Help is much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You API expects your data to be wrapped into `user` parameter. However, according to your schema, you're sending just `profile_image`. You should either remove `require(:user)` from your `update_params` method or rewrite swagger schema in the following manner:

```
parameter do
       key :name, 'user[profile_image]'
       key :in, :formData
       key :type, :file
       key :format, :binary
       key :required, false
       schema do
         key :'$ref', :UserInput
       end
     end
```